# how to check that value entered matches one of autocomplete list items

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a form text input populated with autocomplete and I want to check that the user selected one of the list items and didn't type something different before processing the form.

Can I read in an autocomplete list to a variable?

Reading the list in from an AJAX call:

```
var symbolList = JSON.parse(response);
$(id).autocomplete({
    source: symbolList
    }
});
```

Comment: Isn't your data already in an object of some sort? Some of your code would be most helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Autocomplete has select event as per http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select.  It only triggers if an item from the list was selected.

```
var symbolList = JSON.parse(response);
$(id).autocomplete({
    source: symbolList,
    select: function( event, ui ) {}
    }
});
```

or as a separate listener

```
$(id).on('autocompleteselect', function () {
    ... do some stuff
});
```

Comment: Hi.am also need help to trigger the selection.How I can check if suggested items are not selected and do some action @Chris?